# Object passed to super() referenced by subclass - Any Violations?

Tags: java, design, object-oriented, object-oriented-design, inheritance

This is the code in question, comments point it out:

```
class Actor extends Entity {
    private MutableVector2f position;
    private MutableIdentity identity;

    public Actor(MutableVector2f initialPosition, MutableIdentity initialIdentity) {
        super(initialPosition, initialIdentity); // !! pass to supertype !!

        this.position = initialPosition; // !! reference in subtype !!
        this.identity = initialIdentity; // !! "" "" !!
    }

    public void moveTowards(Vector2f targetPosition) {
        // !! change position member, purpose of keeping reference !!
    }

    public void changeNameTo(String name) {
        identity.changeNameTo(name);
    }
}
```

It seems like a code smell. Is it? Maybe there's a problem with the type structure?

Are there any downfalls to this type of design?

---

The base class `Entity` is used for any object with a position:

```
abstract class Entity {
    private Vector2f position;
    private Identity identity;

    public Entity(Vector2f position, Identity identity) {
        this.position = position;
        this.identity = identity;
    }

   public Vector2f getPosition() {
       return position;
   }

   public Identity getIdentity() {
       return identity;
   }
}
```

The `Actor` subtype has a mutable position to reduce the amount of objects created (could have hundreds of thousands of actors moving around and changing identity)

The `WorldObject` subtype has an immutable position and identity:

```
class WorldObject extends Entity {
    public WorldObject(ImmutableVector2f position, ImmutableIdentity identity) {
        super(position, identity);
    }
}
```

`Vector2f` is an interface which 'ImmutableVector2f`and`MutableVector2f` implement:

```
interface Vector2f {
    float getX();
    float getY();
}
```

`MutableVector2f` exposes methods such as `add`, `multiply` and `normalize`.

`Identity` follows the same structure (is an interface, has immutable and mutable subtypes)

---

I feel this may violate LSP. The purpose of the interfaces is to prevent modification from an `Entity` perspective.

It's not to say `Entity` is immutable, but to discourage mutation at that level of abstraction, since systems using `Entity` should only be reading values.

Keeping a reference in the subclass will prevent the need to cast `Entity#getPosition()`, but it feels wrong. Making the properties generic could lead to a long list of type parameters if I were to continue scaling up `Entity` in this way.

Is it possible that `Entity#getPosition()` should be abstract, and the subtypes should maintain their own position variables? It would require me to declare getters in the subtypes (duplicate code), so I'm not a huge fan of the idea.

Comment: Have you considered using a generic parameter on `Entity` for the type of `Vector2f`?

Comment: @cbojar Yes, but there were a few downsides. The biggest being a long list of type parameters if I continued to scale `Entity` in this way. I also don't want `Actor#getPosition` to be exposed as a `MutableVector2f`, as that'll further encourage users to simply mutate the vector instead of using behavioral methods. Of course they can still cast `Entity#getPosition`, or even use reflection if they really wanted, but the point is to discourage us I such tactics by making the (correct) alternatives easier. I edited my post

Comment: What will `getPosition` return after a call to `moveTowards` - the original value or the updated value? As a user of that class, I'd expect the updated position, but with `getPosition` defined in the base class and using a private non-updated member, it looks to me that it's the original value. (Note: I use C#, not Java, and there might be implementation differences)

Answer (score 1):

If `Entity` specifies in some contract (documentation, comments?) that its position must not change after its initial construction, this violates the LSP (and the invariants of the base class).

If it doesn't explicitly specify such a thing, it may still be an implicit assumption. But given the way Java works, I would not expect such a thing. However, changing `getPosition` to be abstract would make it more explicit that the subclasses have control over the position.

If no such assumption exists, the LSP is not violated.

Comment: "*If it doesn't explicitly specify such a thing, it may still be an implicit assumption*" - I guess that's basically the question at hand: is this bad practice due to the potential assumption that `Entity` is immutable? The contract of `Entity` does not specify immutability, but the type does not expose any mutation behaviors. The only thing specified in the contract of `Entity` is the ability to have a position and an identity, is that bad?

Comment: So add some (doc)comments to the base class that explicitly state such assumptions or the lack thereof.